# 'Add PostSharp to this project' no action

Tags: postsharp

I added PostSharp via NuGet (PostSharp.4.0.40, but I also checked the .39 version), created a class inheriting from *OnExceptionAspect* (e.g. *CustomExceptionBehaviour* - I tested previously this aspect working for me in a sample Console application), how ever on any exception in the method decorated with *CustomExceptionBehaviour* the OnException behaviour doesn't get executed (and checking the generated assembly indeed there is no try-catch inside the method).

The project build output doesn't contain any warnings about PostSharp. 
I checked into the project properties, PostSaharp tab and found the 'Add PostSharp to this project' button but when I click on it nothing happens ...

Any ideas why it's not working ?

Comment: This seems like a bug, installing nuget package should be enough to get postsharp working. It is worth to report this bug [here](https://www.postsharp.net/Support/HelpDesk.aspx?userType=community). Please, could you check csproj file if it contains something like `<Import Project="..\packages\PostSharp.4.0.40\tools\PostSharp.targets"`?

Comment: I added the 4.0.41 version using the _Package Manager Console_ and it worked ok, the issue doesn't reproduce any more.